# Google Play Games, Achievements not showing

Tags: android, google-play-games

I have published my game for alpha testing, but for some reason I cannot see the Achievements in the Google Play Games app, althought I have 5 published achievements. There's just "ABOUT" and "PLAYERS" tabs.

Launching the achievements activity manually in my game does show the achievements.

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Please post your code, maybe it is in your code implementation in the game because you can launch the achievements activity manually.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot Hmm, I'm not sure what code are you talking about? Do I need to setup the achievements somehow? The only "real" code related to achievements is unlocking them when appropriate.

Comment: Yes, have you setup the achievements properly to your app? Here is a check list of the [things-to-do](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements#creating_an_achievement) for creating an achievement. And [adding Achievements to Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/achievements#before_you_begin), this guide shows you how to use the achievements APIs in an Android application to unlock and display achievements in your game.

Comment: Well, yes. I've set up the achievements in the Play Console correctly.

Comment: Have you added the code for unlocking achievement and displaying achievements to your android game? It is given in the second link.

Comment: Yes, for both. It's the Google Play Games App that does not display the achievements.

Comment: Try republishing your app, it is the last thing I would recommend

Comment: @fluxi
Have you figured out, what was the problem?
I have the same situation. Published as closed alpha,
GPGS requirements are met and published as well.
I can call the UI for the achievements per intent as well as I can increment/unlock the achievements.
But the Achievements are not shown in the Google Play Games App.

Answer (score 0):

For latest games, You can't see the achievements unless you unlock one achievement.